# How to get the nth element of an Enumerable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For example, to return the 10,000th prime number I could write:

```
require 'prime'
Prime.first(10000).last #=> 104729
```

But creating a huge intermediate array, just to retrieve its last element feels a bit cumbersome.

Given that Ruby is such an elegant language, I would have expected something like:

```
Prime.at(9999) #=> 104729
```

But there is no `Enumerable#at`.

Is the above workaround intended or is there a more direct way to get the *n*th element  of an `Enumerable`?

Comment: Consider proposing that `Enumerable#at` be added to the Ruby core.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of to a hypothetical `at` method is `drop`, which skips the indicated number of elements. It tries to return an actual array though so you need to combine it with lazy if you are using with infinite sequences, e.g.

```
Prime.lazy.drop(9999).first
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
Prime.to_enum.with_index(1){|e, i| break e if i == 10000}
# => 104729
```

For enumerators that are not lazy, you probably want to put `lazy` on the enumerator.

Comment: That avoids the intermediate array, but unfortunately, it's even more cumbersome. Any idea why there is no built-in method like `Enumerable#at`?

Comment: Probably it is because if you are only interested in a particular value, then there should be a method that returns such value directly, rather than being an enumerator. For primes, I think there would be more use cases when you want the n-th one, rather than going through from the beginning. So the `Prime` class is not designed the way it should be, or is affected too much by its internal algorithm.

Comment: I would assume it's because when we are using an `Enumerable`, most of the time we are actually interested in the enumeration of objects, not one at a particular index, and an `Enumerable#at` is not hard to write - see @sawa example. But that's just an opinion - I wouldn't know if that's indeed the correct assumption.

Comment: @Stefan Most of the time enumerable objects are actually not unbound but are backed by some finite data structure (e.g. an `Array`, or `Hash`). There, it is quite efficient to get the n-th element directly from the data structure, without having to enumerate the list, e.g. `my_array[10]`. If all you have is an (unbound) list as is the case here, you have no choice but to get all elements and to drop those you are not interested in. In the end, all of the functionality provided by the `Enumerable` module is based on the object implementing the `each` method to loop over its arbitrary elements.

Comment: @HolgerJust that's correct and I'm fully aware that the enumeration can't be skipped from within `Enumerable`. But that doesn't explain, why `Enumerable#at` is missing, does it? `Array` could still provide its own (faster) implementation for `at`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [sawa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34853253/477037), here's a more succinct alternative:

```
Prime.find.with_index(1) { |_, i| i == 10000 }
#=> 104729
```

or

```
Prime.find.with_index { |_, i| i == 9999 }
#=> 104723
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module Enumerable
  def at(n)
    enum = is_a?(Enumerator) ? self : each
    (n-1).times { enum.next }
    enum.next
  end
end
```

```
(0..4).at(3)
  #=> 2 
{ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 }.at(3)
  #=> [:c, 3] 
'0ab_1ab_2ab_3ab_4ab'.gsub(/.(?=ab)/).at(3)
  #=> "2" 
require 'prime'; Prime.at(10000)
  #=> 104729 
e = 1.step; e.at(10)
  #=> 10 
[0,1,2,3,4].at(6)
  #=> nil 
'0ab_1ab_2ab_3ab_4ab'.gsub(/.(?=ab)/).at(6)
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

Note that `'0ab_1ab_2ab_3ab_4ab'.gsub(/.(?=ab)/).class #=> Enumerator`.

Some refinements would be needed, such as checking that `n` is an integer greater than zero and improving the exception handling, such as dealing with the case when `self` is not an enumerator but has no method `each`.